# Autoincrement variable in a loop

Tags: applescript

I need to autoincrement a variable in a loop for Automator. 
I have no idea to do it... I'm very new in AppleScript, have been looking around and googling but didn't find much info.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
set myVar to 10

repeat with i from 1 to 5
    set newVar to myVar + i
    display dialog (newVar)
end repeat
```

Did this help?

Comment: mmm... I suppose, yes. But... It's possible to insert Automator Actions inside this repeat ... end loop ?